# Configure kernel with fault-injection enabled

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel

I'm trying to use the Linux fault injection framework to simulate faults.
I'm using ubuntu 16.04 LTS (4.15.0-33-generic), but i didn't find any way to "activate" the FI framework. How do I configure the kernel with fault-injection enabled?

Answer (score 0):

The Ubuntu kernel is configured without `CONFIG_FAULT_INJECTION`, so it doesn’t have any of the fault injection framework.

To be able to inject faults, you’ll need to rebuild a kernel, with the appropriate configuration. On Ubuntu, the simplest way to do this is to [follow the Ubuntu instructions](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel) — that way you’ll get the appropriate base configuration and any Ubuntu patches.